# SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Query very slow greater than 250000 records

Tags: php, mysql

This query was working fine when our table records less than 150K but since it is not working fine & very slow -

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS main_article.* 
FROM main_articles 
LEFT JOIN main_members 
ON article_mem_id=member_id 
WHERE `article_type`='2' 
ORDER BY article_id 
DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

How can I improve my query?

Comment: other than adding indexes to your `where` clause's fields, there's nothing you can do. you're forcing the db to scan the entire table for all possible matches so it can do the found rows calculation.

Answer (score 6):

There's a good description in this blog: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

The demonstration shows that yes, using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is very bad for performance when you use it on a large table.

It is often better to run two queries separately:

```
/* no need to do the join in this case, because it won't affect the count */
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM main_articles 
WHERE `article_type`='2' 

SELECT main_article.* 
FROM main_articles 
LEFT JOIN main_members 
ON article_mem_id=member_id 
WHERE `article_type`='2' 
ORDER BY article_id 
DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

By the way, this is not related to the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS issue, but I wonder why you are joining to the `main_members` table. You aren't fetching any columns from it. The LEFT JOIN means that it won't restrict the rows. If I can infer the table relationship from the column names, there can be only one row in `main_members` for each row in `main_articles`, so the join won't increase the number of rows either. So there's really no purpose to doing this join.