# How to use orWhere() optimally in the query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Here is my query:

```
$notifications = \App\Notification::query()->where('users_scope', 'customer')
   ->with('userSeen')
   ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('user_id_to', 20288)
        ->orWhere(function($q) use ($user) {
            $q->Where('user_id_to', null)
              ->Where(function($q) use ($user) {
                    $q->where('expire_at', null)->where('created_at', '>=', "2020-04-03 04:18:42");
                    $q->orWhere('expire_at', '!=', null)->where('expire_at', '>', Carbon::now());
                });
        });
    })
    ->select([DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *')])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
```

Also here is the relation (used as `with()`):

```
public function userSeen()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, NotificationSeen::class, 'notification_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Here is the scenario: Query above gets the last 20 user's notifications (latest notifications list). Recently, the size of the `notifications` table is increased too much. It has over 8 million rows at the moment. And the query takes over 10 seconds to be executed.

Noted that, all needed indexes have been created as well on both tables (`notifications` and `userSeen` tables). Also, that relation (`userSeen`) is like a pivot table that indicates the user either has seen the notification or not.

Any idea how can I rewrite that query to be more optimal?

---

Explanations about the logic:

- `20288` is hardcoded and will be `$user->id` in reality.
- when `user_id_to` is `null`, it means it's a bulk notification (must be visible for all users)
- User can see bulk notifications if they have a bigger `created_at` value than the user's `created_at`.
- Sometimes bulk notifications has an expire time (like marketing campaigns) that must be shown to the users if still not outdated.

Comment: Please can you add a little explanation for the around the `$user` logic, i.e. is `20288` meant to be hard coded or should it be `$user->id`, how is the `null` user bit is meant to work, and which bits of the `expire_at`/`created_at` are meant to be grouped?

Comment: Oh, you are right @Rwd .. I will add some explanations about the logic ..

Answer (score 1):

Bases on the logic you mentioned in your question, this should get you what you need, however, it probably won't help that much with the speed:

```
$notifications = \App\Notification::query()
    ->select([DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *')])
    ->with('userSeen')
    ->where('users_scope', 'customer')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query
            ->where('user_id_to', $user->id)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query
                    ->whereNull('user_id_to')
                    ->where('created_at', '>=', $user->created_at)
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->whereNull('expire_at')->orWhere('expire_at', '>=', now());
                    });
            });
    })
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->limit(20)
    ->get();
```

---

I would also suggest trying 2 separate queries instead of using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Here are a couple of SO posts that explain why:

[Which is fastest? SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM `table`, or SELECT COUNT(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count)
[SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Query very slow greater than 250000 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163821/select-sql-calc-found-rows-query-very-slow-greater-than-250000-records)

You queries would then look something like:

```
$query = \App\Notification::query()
    ->with('userSeen')
    ->where('users_scope', 'customer')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query
            ->where('user_id_to', $user->id)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query
                    ->whereNull('user_id_to')
                    ->where('created_at', '>=', $user->created_at)
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->whereNull('expire_at')->orWhere('expire_at', '>=', now());
                    });
            });
    })
    ->orderByDesc('id');

$count = $query->count();
$notifications = $query->limit(20)->get();
```

Alternatively, you could use something like [paginate()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what condition you have but condition you can apply like below

```
$notifications = \App\Notification::query()->where('users_scope', 'customer')
        ->with('userSeen')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user_id_to', 20288);
                if($user){
                    $query->orWhere(function($q) use ($user) {
                        $q->Where('user_id_to', null)
                            ->Where(function($q) use ($user) {
                                $q->where('expire_at', null)->where('created_at', '>=', "2020-04-03 04:18:42");
                                $q->orWhere('expire_at', '!=', null)->where('expire_at', '>', Carbon::now());
                            });
                    });
                }

        })
        ->select([DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *')])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
```

Even you can use when clause
Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses